# Ler valor de array em jade

Tags: node.js, jade

Tenho o seguinte array criado em meu controller:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    nfejs(array[i], function(err, nfe) {
        var itemNfe = {};
        itemNfe.name = nfe.identificador.getNumero();
        data.push(itemNfe);
    });
}

nfe.data = data;
```

Que é gerado do seguinte modo:

```
data:[{
    name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, default: ""},
}],
```

Estou tentando ler no jade conforme abaixo, porém não funciona:

```
table#nfe.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover.dt-responsive  
          thead  
            tr  
              th(style='text-align: center') Nome  
                th(style='text-align: center; width: 25%') Ação  
          tbody  
            for nfe in nfes  
              tr  
                td(style='text-align: center') #{nfe[data].name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens um problema de assincronismo. O teu ciclo `for` está a correr funções assíncronas, e o ciclo acaba antes de as funções terem sido corridas.

Ou seja a orde de eventos é:

```
> começa o ciclo for 
  > inicia as funçöes assíncronas 
    > acaba o ciclo for 
      > corre "nfe.data = data;" 
        > as respostas das funções chamadas dentro do for começam a chegar
```

Para resolver isso tens de esperar que as funções assíncronas tenham corrido. Eu uso habitualmente a [biblioteca `async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) para fazer isso. Nesse caso o código poderia ser assim:

```js
var async = require('async');
async.map(array, function(el, cb) {
    nfejs(el, function(err, nfe) {
        var itemNfe = {};
        itemNfe.name = nfe.identificador.getNumero();
        cb(err, itemNfe); // quando "nfejs" tiver dado a resposta, chama a callback "cb"
    });
}, function(err, res) { // esta é a callback final, ou seja quando tiver chamado e recebido todas as "nfejs"
    nfe.data = res;
    // aqui os dados estão disponíveis e só agora (dentro desta callback)
    // é que podes correr ou chamar código que precise de "nfe.data"
});
```

E depois no Jade podes usar assim:

```
tbody  
  each nfe in nfes.data
    tr  
      td(style='text-align: center') #{nfe.name}
```

Comment: Não estou com problema para montar o array, o mesmo está correto. Minha dificuldade está em como ler no jade.

Comment: @Nodejs ok, se a função `nfejs` é síncrona, então só precisas de corrigir no Jade. Juntei isso à resposta.

Comment: @Nodejs uma possível dúvida: estás a passar o `nfes` para o Jade certo? nesse caso coloquei na resposta `each nfe in nfes.data`, mas se já passas somente `nfes.data` para o Jade, podes ter somente `each nfe in nfes` ou a variável que usares.